# Function using a local static variable thread safe/reentrant

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety

I have a function that will generate a unique random number(basically increment previous) to different threads invoking it.

Is this thread safe or is this reentrant.Assume I used static variable for this number.

I have seen in this forum static variables cant be used for reentrant/thread safe.

Does it applies for local/global static.

Or is it implementation defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, local `static` variables are initialized in a thread-safe manner because they're always initialized at program startup, before any threads can be created.  It is not allowed to initialize local `static` variables with non-constant values for precisely that reason.

```
void some_function(int arg)
{
    // This initialization is thread-safe and reentrant, since it happens at
    // program startup
    static int my_static = 42;

    // ERROR: Initializer is not constant
    static int another_static = arg;
    ...
}
```

Of course, whether or not the entire function is thread-safe or reentrant depends entirely on how you *use* the static variables.  Since they're effectively identical to global variables, you need to make sure to use proper mutexes when reading or writing them (or other synchronization structures) to ensure thread safety.

In order to ensure that the function is reentrant, you need to carefully examine when and how the function can call itself (perhaps indirectly via another function) and make sure that all global state behaves consistently.

Comment: I have heard they are initialized the first time the point of execution reaches them. Or is that only c++?

Comment: @Anders: That is in C++, not C.  From C99 §6.2.4/3: "An object whose identifier is declared [...] with the storage-class specifier `static` has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire
execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup."

Comment: Which definition of *global variables* are you using?

Comment: @Anders POD types are initialised at load-time in C++ as in C (that is, in the ctor for a static global, you can interact with other globals before their constructors are called, a common bug, but you can never write code that sees a static int before it acquires the initial value you give it).

Answer (score 4):

Changing an "ordinary" object that is shared between threads is never thread safe, unless you take special care of it. (and any statically declared variable falls in that category). There are two standard ways of dealing with that

- use a mutex or other lock structure to protect the shared object inside a "critical section"
- use atomic operations to access the object, the new C standard, C11 has interfaces for this

Being reentrant asks if an execution (even without threads) can modify part of the state, examples are recursion, signal handlers or jumps with `goto` or `longjmp`. Think of it as sharing a variable with "yourself". Statically allocated variables make the same problems here, if you modify them from different places of the program.