# Static variable in a loop vs variable and a loop in a block

Tags: c, loops, static

In C we can use blocks to restrict the scope of a variable, so is

```c
{
    int var = /* initialization */;

    while(...) {
        // some stuff with var
    }
}
```

equivalent to

```c
while(...) {
    static int var = /* initialization */;
    // some stuff with var
}
```

?

Comment: it is not equivalent, static variable will be initialized only once, so second time you call the same function - it will hold previous value

Comment: Scope is a property of an identifier, not (directly) of the object or function it identifies.  On the other hand, inside a function definition, the `static` keyword is about storage duration, which is a property of an object, not of its identifier, if any.  In particular, `static` specifies a storage duration different from the default for objects declared inside function definitions, and that does have an impact.  Do not confuse identifiers themselves with the objects and functions they identify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

- The initializer of the one with the `static` keyword must be constant.

  ```c
  {
     int var = f();
     for ( int j=0; j<2; ++j ) {
        printf( "%d\n", var++ );
     }
  }

  printf( "--\n" );

  for ( int j=0; j<2; ++j ) {
     static int var = f();
     printf( "%d\n", var++ );
  }
  ```

  ```
  <source>: In function 'main':
  <source>:18:24: error: initializer element is not constant
     18 |       static int var = f();
        |
  ```
- The one with the `static` keyword exists for the duration of the program, and it will only be initialized once no matter how many times the code is executed. If that code block is in a loop that's executed more than once or in a function that's called more than once, it won't get initialized as often as desired.

  ```c
  for ( int i=0; i<2; ++i ) {
     int var = 3;
     for ( int j=0; j<2; ++j ) {
        printf( "%d\n", var++ );
     }
  }

  printf( "--\n" );

  for ( int i=0; i<2; ++i ) {
     for ( int j=0; j<2; ++j ) {
        static int var = 3;
        printf( "%d\n", var++ );
     }
  }
  ```

  ```
  3
  4
  3
  4
  --
  3
  4
  5
  6
  ```
- There is only one instance of the variable with the `static` keyword for the entire program, so it is thus shared by all threads.

Comment: Additionally, the implementation using `static` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347928/function-using-a-local-static-variable-thread-safe-reentrant it's thread-safe because it's initialized at the start of the program. It depends of what you do with the variable.

Comment: @zonn Did you **read** that entire question and **answer**?  Given `static int var = 3;` or similar, any access at all to `var` from multiple threads is a race condition and thread-**un**safe if the variable is modified in any way by any one of the threads.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what I meant is that (from what I understand) static variables are not inherently thread-unsafe, we just need to be careful and use mutex and atomic operations for example to act on them.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Thanks. Mentioned threads.

Comment: @zonn, Andrew Henle only said that the snippet in the OP isn't thread-safe, not that it couldn't be made safe, and not that one can't use static variables in mutliple threads.

Comment: @ikegami ok, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly worth bearing in mind where each variable is stored in memory too, static variables are in the data segment where as local variables are placed on the stack.

Comment: ... This means `static` variables can typically be larger, and you can return a pointer to a `static` variable.

Comment: Although, on most modern implementations, local variables are, indeed placed on the stack, there is no *formal* requirement in the C Standard that this is so. They could (legally) be allocated on the heap.